# Cannot run jnlp Java file using jre7

Tags: java, windows-7, jnlp

Cannot run on Windows7 jnlp file using jre7. `java.exe` nor `javaws.exe` are able to open it. How to open it?

[image]

And another jnlp from trusted authority cannot be displayed:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
  Setting javaws.exe as default pprogram from jdk instead of jre7 folder solved problem. No idea why jre7 was not working...

Comment: What is the content of the JNLP?  Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  What is the output at time of failure?

Comment: The file was taken from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/antiplagiarismc/

Comment: Don't post screen grabs of JaNeLA output, it has a  menu that allows to copy the **text** and will provide a report that summarizes the info.